# How to perform multiple left joins using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I join multiple dataframes in R using `dplyr` ?

```
new <- left_join(x,y, by = "Flag")
```

this is the code I am using to left join x and y
the code doesn't work for multiple joins

```
new <- left_join(x,y,z by = "Flag")
```

Comment: [This is how you join multiple data sets in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) usually. You can use `left_join` instead of `merge` if you like.

Comment: Use `Reduce(function(dtf1,dtf2) left_join(dtf1,dtf2,by="index"), list(x,y,z))`. Since this question is marked as duplicate, I gave a detailed answer with example on the question [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34393416/2641825).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can use a nested `left_join`

```
 library(dplyr)
 left_join(x, y, by='Flag') %>%
                left_join(., z, by='Flag')
```

Or another option would be to place all the datasets in a `list` and use `merge` from `base R` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='Flag', all.x=TRUE), list(x,y,z))
```

Or we have `join_all` from `plyr`.  Here we place the dataframes in a `list` and use the argument `type='left'` for a left join.

```
library(plyr)
join_all(list(x,y,z), by='Flag', type='left')
```

---

As @JBGruber mentioned in the comments, it can also be done via `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
purrr::reduce(list(x,y,z), dplyr::left_join, by = 'Flag')
```

Comment: I guess you can just embed `left_join` into `Reduce` too, but it seems this was already asked a few times yesterday, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it can be and is useful for multiple datasets.  I just thought to use the `%>%` .

Comment: The pipe option and reduce with join_left are much faster (1.8s) (~10x faster in my case- conditional to your data of course etc..). Reduce with merge is very slow (16s) but if you replace merge with left_join then you have comparable speed as with the pipe (wee bit slower 1.9s on average but not significant). The slowest is join_all from plyr (22s).

Comment: @R.Prost  I think `dplyr` is more optimized for those joins

Comment: this is great... it seems obvious that the `.` in the second join is a placeholder for the first join, but can anyone explain that in functional programming terms? why is the `.` deemed as the placeholder? Is this something to do with NSE?

Comment: @akrun How can i force R to retain the names of the dataframes in the columns of the new object? I am getting "value.x", "value.x.x." and so on.

Comment: @nouse  You could select only the columns that are really needed so that othere than the `by` columns, there would be unique names in both datasets.  If there are duplicate column names, that will append the `.x` `x.x` etc.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate suffixes into to the nested left_join option? For example if you wanted to assign "_T1", "_T2"...etc to all columns in each data frame.

Comment: @AddisonMaerz there is a default option `suffix = c(".x", ".y")` which you can change

Comment: @akrun but how would it work if you are joining more than two datasets? My understanding is that the character vector for that option has to be two. So in the second level of left_join, is there some place holder you can enter (e.g., c(., ".z")

Comment: @AddisonMaerz can you post as a new question as it is not clear abou tyour particular case

Comment: Can you please explain the use of the `.` in the 2nd join? Perhaps a reference link? I can' seem to find information about this anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyBullis In tidyverse, the `.` refers to the entire object from the lhs of `%>%`  So, it is the data.frame created from the left join of x and y

Comment: Hey @akrun, this is the first hit on Google and it's a great answer. Could you update it to include `purrr::reduce` since this is, I believe, the best current option `purrr::reduce(list(x,y,z), dplyr::left_join, by = 'Flag')`.

Comment: Loved the `reduce() merge()` combination. Say you collected from the environment a list of frequency dataframes and you wanted to combine them by a 'hallmarks' column: 

`df_list=mget((ls(pattern=".*_freq")))

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='hallmarks', all.x=TRUE), df_list )`