# Can I join more than 4 dataframes in dplyr?

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr

I am trying to combine the results of 5 models into a single dataframe for presentation purposes using `dplyr` and `left_join`. Each model result exists in its own dataframe (dat1 through dat5 for demonstration purposes).

*This is the result of a home-brewed likelihood function, so no summary methods available to exploit through things like `mtable` in the `memisc` package or the options available in `stargazer`.

```
label1 <- paste0("var", 1:10)
beta1 <- 1:10
se1 <- 1:10*.01
p1 <- 1:10*.005

dat1 <- data.frame(label = label1
                   ,beta = beta1
                   ,se = se1
                   ,p = p1)


label2 <- paste0("var", 1:4)
beta2 <- 1:4
se2 <- 1:4*.01
p2 <- 1:4*.005

dat2 <- data.frame(label = label2
                   ,beta = beta2
                   ,se = se2
                   ,p = p2)


label3 <- paste0("var", 1:3)
beta3 <- 1:3
se3 <- 1:3*.01
p3 <- 1:3*.005

dat3 <- data.frame(label = label3
                   ,beta = beta3
                   ,se = se3
                   ,p = p3)

label4 <- paste0("var", 1:2)
beta4 <- 1:2
se4 <- 1:2*.01
p4 <- 1:2*.005

dat4 <- data.frame(label = label4
                   ,beta = beta4
                   ,se = se4
                   ,p = p4)

label5 <- paste0("var", 1)
beta5 <- 1
se5 <- 1*.01
p5 <- 1*.005

dat5 <- data.frame(label = label5
                   ,beta = beta5
                   ,se = se5
                   ,p = p5)
```

In regular SQL, I would expect a LEFT JOIN function to behave as it does in `sqldf` as shown below.

```
sqldf(
"
select * 
from dat1
  left join dat2
    on dat1.label = dat2.label
  left join dat3
    on dat1.label = dat3.label
  left join dat4
    on dat1.label = dat4.label
"
)

#label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p
#1   var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010
#3   var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#4   var4    4 0.04 0.020  var4    4 0.04 0.020  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#5   var5    5 0.05 0.025  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#6   var6    6 0.06 0.030  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#7   var7    7 0.07 0.035  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#8   var8    8 0.08 0.040  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#9   var9    9 0.09 0.045  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#10 var10   10 0.10 0.050  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
```

Ignoring the repeated column headers from regular SQL, I can replicate the same thing in `dplyr` as shown below.

```
dat1 %>% left_join(dat2,  by = c("label" = "label")) %>%
  left_join(dat3,  by = c("label" = "label")) %>%
  left_join(dat4,  by = c("label" = "label"))

#label beta.x se.x   p.x beta.y se.y   p.y beta.x se.x   p.x beta.y se.y   p.y
#1   var1      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010
#3   var3      3 0.03 0.015      3 0.03 0.015      3 0.03 0.015     NA   NA    NA
#4   var4      4 0.04 0.020      4 0.04 0.020     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
#5   var5      5 0.05 0.025     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
#6   var6      6 0.06 0.030     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
#7   var7      7 0.07 0.035     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
#8   var8      8 0.08 0.040     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
#9   var9      9 0.09 0.045     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
#10 var10     10 0.10 0.050     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA     NA   NA    NA
```

In regular SQL, I can add a 5th table to the mix and get the expected result.

```
sqldf(
  "
select * 
from dat1
  left join dat2
    on dat1.label = dat2.label
  left join dat3
    on dat1.label = dat3.label
  left join dat4
    on dat1.label = dat4.label
  left join dat5
    on dat1.label = dat5.label
"
)

#label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p
#1   var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#3   var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#4   var4    4 0.04 0.020  var4    4 0.04 0.020  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#5   var5    5 0.05 0.025  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#6   var6    6 0.06 0.030  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#7   var7    7 0.07 0.035  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#8   var8    8 0.08 0.040  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#9   var9    9 0.09 0.045  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#10 var10   10 0.10 0.050  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
```

In `dplyr`, although I appear to join `dat5`, I end up dropping `dat3` and `dat4`, and repeating the results of `dat1` and `dat2`.

```
dat1 %>% left_join(dat2,  by = c("label" = "label")) %>%
  left_join(dat3,  by = c("label" = "label")) %>%
  left_join(dat4,  by = c("label" = "label")) %>%
  left_join(dat5,  by = c("label" = "label")) 

#label beta.x se.x   p.x beta.y se.y   p.y beta.x se.x   p.x beta.y se.y   p.y beta   se     p
#1   var1      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005    1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010   NA   NA    NA
#3   var3      3 0.03 0.015      3 0.03 0.015      3 0.03 0.015      3 0.03 0.015   NA   NA    NA
#4   var4      4 0.04 0.020      4 0.04 0.020      4 0.04 0.020      4 0.04 0.020   NA   NA    NA
#5   var5      5 0.05 0.025     NA   NA    NA      5 0.05 0.025     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
#6   var6      6 0.06 0.030     NA   NA    NA      6 0.06 0.030     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
#7   var7      7 0.07 0.035     NA   NA    NA      7 0.07 0.035     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
#8   var8      8 0.08 0.040     NA   NA    NA      8 0.08 0.040     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
#9   var9      9 0.09 0.045     NA   NA    NA      9 0.09 0.045     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
#10 var10     10 0.10 0.050     NA   NA    NA     10 0.10 0.050     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA    NA
```

**Am I porting the join to `dat5` in `dplyr` properly?**

**Is it possible to execute this many joins in `dplyr`?**

EDIT1: I believe this is distinct from ([How to perform multiple left joins using dplyr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066402)). `Reduce` appeared to solve the problem outlined there.

In my case, `Reduce` produces the same result shown in my last code chunk above.

EDIT2: To be clear, I am not concerned with the multiple left-join syntax. I am trying to determine why greater than 4 joins do not behave as they do in "regular" SQL.

EDIT 3: While I had initially accepted an answer from @akrun below, I realized now that the following output:

```
lst <- lapply(mget(paste0("dat", 1:5)), transform, label2 = label)
suppressWarnings( Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., by = "label"), lst))

#label beta.x se.x   p.x label2.x beta.y se.y   p.y label2.y beta.x se.x   p.x label2.x beta.y se.y   p.y label2.y beta   se     p label2
#1   var1      1 0.01 0.005     var1      1 0.01 0.005     var1      1 0.01 0.005     var1      1 0.01 0.005     var1    1 0.01 0.005   var1
#2   var2      2 0.02 0.010     var2      2 0.02 0.010     var2      2 0.02 0.010     var2      2 0.02 0.010     var2   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  3   var3      3 0.03 0.015     var3      3 0.03 0.015     var3      3 0.03 0.015     var3      3 0.03 0.015     var3   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  4   var4      4 0.04 0.020     var4      4 0.04 0.020     var4      4 0.04 0.020     var4      4 0.04 0.020     var4   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  5   var5      5 0.05 0.025     var5     NA   NA    NA     <NA>      5 0.05 0.025     var5     NA   NA    NA     <NA>   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  6   var6      6 0.06 0.030     var6     NA   NA    NA     <NA>      6 0.06 0.030     var6     NA   NA    NA     <NA>   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  7   var7      7 0.07 0.035     var7     NA   NA    NA     <NA>      7 0.07 0.035     var7     NA   NA    NA     <NA>   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  8   var8      8 0.08 0.040     var8     NA   NA    NA     <NA>      8 0.08 0.040     var8     NA   NA    NA     <NA>   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  9   var9      9 0.09 0.045     var9     NA   NA    NA     <NA>      9 0.09 0.045     var9     NA   NA    NA     <NA>   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
#  10 var10     10 0.10 0.050    var10     NA   NA    NA     <NA>     10 0.10 0.050    var10     NA   NA    NA     <NA>   NA   NA    NA   <NA>
```

Is still distinct from

```
sqldf(
  "
select * 
from dat1
  left join dat2
    on dat1.label = dat2.label
  left join dat3
    on dat1.label = dat3.label
  left join dat4
    on dat1.label = dat4.label
  left join dat5
    on dat1.label = dat5.label
"
)

#label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p
#1   var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#3   var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#4   var4    4 0.04 0.020  var4    4 0.04 0.020  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#5   var5    5 0.05 0.025  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#6   var6    6 0.06 0.030  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#7   var7    7 0.07 0.035  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#8   var8    8 0.08 0.040  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#9   var9    9 0.09 0.045  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#10 var10   10 0.10 0.050  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
```

I am still losing `dat3` and `dat4`...

EDIT 4: Not sure why, but my confusion below may have been partly a version issue. @akrun's final answer works on `dplyr_0.4.3` and `R version 3.3.0` (apparently Linux (Ubuntu) and PC).

**EDIT 5: I think @akrun and I are both running the dev version of `dplyr` (which is why I first had problems running @akrun's solution on my windows machine which is using production `dplyr`.) As noted [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1906) this problem has been addressed in the most recent dev version of `dplyr`.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform multiple left joins using dplyr in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066402/how-to-perform-multiple-left-joins-using-dplyr-in-r)

Comment: Among the sql code blocks, which one is the expected output?

Comment: @steven-beaupré...See comments to the answer below. I am not interested in how to avoid the multiple join syntax. I want to figure out why 4+ joins are behaving as shown.

Comment: @akrun, the second-to-last sql chunk is my desired end-state.

Comment: I guess the `Reduce` gets the same output as the first block of `sql`

Comment: @akrun, indeed it does. It certainly reduces the left join syntax (as noted in the alleged duplicate), but it still does not behave as I would expect.

Comment: Can you check the updated output

Comment: @akrun, that does it!

Comment: @akrun, I spoke too soon! your revised answer does give me a second label column, but it still drops `dat3` and `dat4` (that's the most important part - the rest is superfluous).

Comment: Seems like the duplicate column names that aren't being joined on are messing up `dplyr`. Maybe a bug, but a workaround might be to append an data frame identifier to all the column names (except label). I think the joins would work well then, and then the column names of the end result could be modified back to whatever you want.

Comment: @gregor, not sure if this is a bug or not, but I agree that the join functions of dplyr are trying to ensure that the resulting dataframe has unique column headings. In general, I think this is desirable, although it might be nice to be able to ignore (i.e. `unique_columns = FALSE`). This could result in behavior that is similar to left joins in vanilla sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `left_join` after placing the datasets in a `list`.

```
Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., by = "label"), mget(paste0("dat", 1:5)))
```

---

If we need the `label` columns, we can create one more column

```
lst <- lapply(mget(paste0("dat", 1:5)), transform, label2 = label)
lst[[1]]["label2"] <- NULL
res1 <- suppressWarnings( Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., by = "label"), lst))
res1
#   label beta.x se.x   p.x beta.y se.y   p.y label2.x beta.x.x se.x.x p.x.x label2.y beta.y.y se.y.y p.y.y label2.x.x beta   se     p
#1   var1      1 0.01 0.005      1 0.01 0.005     var1        1   0.01 0.005     var1        1   0.01 0.005       var1    1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2      2 0.02 0.010      2 0.02 0.010     var2        2   0.02 0.010     var2        2   0.02 0.010       var2   NA   NA    NA
#3   var3      3 0.03 0.015      3 0.03 0.015     var3        3   0.03 0.015     var3       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#4   var4      4 0.04 0.020      4 0.04 0.020     var4       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#5   var5      5 0.05 0.025     NA   NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#6   var6      6 0.06 0.030     NA   NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#7   var7      7 0.07 0.035     NA   NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#8   var8      8 0.08 0.040     NA   NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#9   var9      9 0.09 0.045     NA   NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#10 var10     10 0.10 0.050     NA   NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA     <NA>       NA     NA    NA       <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#   label2.y.y
#1        var1
#2        <NA>
#3        <NA>
#4        <NA>
#5        <NA>
#6        <NA>
#7        <NA>
#8        <NA>
#9        <NA>
#10       <NA>
```

Here is the OP's output from the second `sqldf` code block

```
res2
#   label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p label beta   se     p
#1   var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005  var1    1 0.01 0.005
#2   var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  var2    2 0.02 0.010  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#3   var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  var3    3 0.03 0.015  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#4   var4    4 0.04 0.020  var4    4 0.04 0.020  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#5   var5    5 0.05 0.025  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#6   var6    6 0.06 0.030  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#7   var7    7 0.07 0.035  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#8   var8    8 0.08 0.040  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#9   var9    9 0.09 0.045  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA
#10 var10   10 0.10 0.050  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA  <NA>   NA   NA    NA


dim(res1)
#[1] 10 20
dim(res2)
#[1] 10 20
```

Comment: Reduce produces the same output given in my last codechunk above...it drops dat3 and dat4.

Comment: @joemienko I thought you want to avoid multiple `left_join` syntax

Comment: my apologies. I don't mind the multiple left join syntax. I am trying to determine why the result behaves as it does.

Comment: your revised answer does work - it seems like it would make sense for a user to be able to specify the joins explicitly, however.

Comment: @joemienko  As we are using the 'label' in the `by` column, it is not available to be returned as another column.  So we need to create a copy of that column.

Comment: I spoke too soon! your revised answer does give me a second label column, but it still drops `dat3` and `dat4` (that's the most important part - the rest is superfluous).

Comment: @joemienko  I looked at the output.  It only gives a single extra column as it also provides `label2` for the first dataset.  which we can remove or avoid creating.  Regarding the `dat3` and `dat4` part, I compared both the `sqldf` (2nd output) with the new result.  Couldn't find any noticeable difference.

Comment: my apologies again, I had wanted to point you to "second-to-last" output. I have edited the post again to make my desired output more clear.

Comment: @joemienko The dimensions are the same for the result.  So, I am not sure where exactly it is losing.  I guess the order of the columns are a bit different if you look at it closely.

Comment: You are getting the results that I want - I am just unable to reproduce on my end.

Comment: @joemienko I am not sure why you are not getting the same results. I use `R 3.3.0` and `dplyr_0.4.3.9001`

Comment: dplyr_0.4.3 and R version 3.2.5 here - although I can't imagine that the R version would be causing me difficulty...I will try on a different box and see what I come up with

Comment: your solution works on my linux box - I'll call that good enough :)