# How to merge several data frames using a loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the code below, which I thought would let me merge several data frames together.

```
codes <- c('agglevel','industry','ownership','size','area')
ann2012full <- ann2012
for(i in 1:length(codes)){
eval(parse(text=paste('ann2012full <- left_join(ann2012full,
',codes[i],')', sep='')))
}
```

It seems like the first 3 files merge fine, and when I get the 4th file, I get this error message.

```
Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
  Can't join on 'own_code' x 'own_code' because of incompatible types (integer / character)
```

I'm guessing there must be a way to coerce the integers into characters, and do the merge, right.  I am just not sure how to get this to work.  I was hoping for an elegant looping option, rather than doing this 5 separate and distinct ways.  Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Comment: Also @akrun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066402/how-to-perform-multiple-left-joins-using-dplyr-in-r)

Comment: Isn't there a way to get R to find common field names between different DFs and do the merge, rather then explicitly writing out how merge should be done?

Comment: `merge` does this anyway. It merges on common columns by default.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Everything is working now.  Thanks guys!