# Joining multiple tibbles in R

Tags: r

Hi I have 3 tibbles called 'A', 'B' and 'C', each has a column entitled 'Area' and some additional columns. I am looking to merge all 3 in to one tibble that has joins on 'Area' and keeps the other columns.

I have tried, can anyone correct please?

```
Testertable <- merge(A, B, C, by "Area")

Testertable  <- full_join(A,  B, C, by = "Area")
```

Comment: Use two steps, first join B on A and then C on the result of the first join. (i.e. `Testertable <- A %>% full_join(B) %>% full_join(C)` (since the common columns all have the same name we might not need to specify the `by` argument)

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066402/how-to-perform-multiple-left-joins-using-dplyr-in-r/32066419