# Multiple left join with different column names

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have two `left_join` operations:

```
unnested = left_join(unnested, X3g_data[,c(1:6)], by = c("Country" = "CountryName"), all.x = TRUE)

unnested = left_join(unnested, new_data, by = "Country", all.x = TRUE)
```

I want to combine them into one `left_join` command, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066402/how-to-perform-multiple-left-joins-using-dplyr-in-r), but it assumes that the column names are the same, which is not the case for me.

How can combine these two operations into a single operation?

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe (`%>%`) these together:

```r
library(tidyverse)

unnested %>% 
  left_join(X3g_data[,c(1:6)], 
            by = c("Country" = "CountryName")) %>% 
  left_join(new_data, 
            by = "Country")
```

Another option is to adjust the input data so the merging columns are the same for all and then use `purrr::reduce()`:

```r
list(unnested,
     rename(X3g_data[,c(1:6)], Country = CountryName),
     new_data) %>% 
  reduce(left_join)
```