# How to write a function to combine a group of dataframe and give them a new name seperately?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, merge

I have imported several groups of `.csv` files in R, and named them as follows:

```
DEMO, DEMO_B, DEMO_C, DEMO_D
DIQ, DIQ_B, DIQ_C, DIQ_D
MCQ, MCQ_B, MCQ_C, MCQ_D
MORT, MORT_B, MORT_C, MORT_C
```

I would like to to create a series of new dataframes as follows:

```
Merg = DEMO + DIQ + MCQ + MORT
Merg_B = DEMO_B + DIQ_B + MCQ_B + MORT_B
...
```

I have done it step by step, but it is too anoying to change names one by one, and would better to have a loop or function, thanks guys!

```
Merg <- DEMO %>%
dplyr::left_join(DIQ, by = join_by(SEQN == SEQN)) %>%
dplyr::left_join(MCQ, by = join_by(SEQN == SEQN)) %>%
dplyr::left_join(Mort, by = join_by(SEQN == SEQN)) %>%
dplyr::select(1:7,9:12)
```

Comment: Essentially what you're trying to do is left-join a series of dataframes. @Akrun has answered a very similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066402/how-to-perform-multiple-left-joins-using-dplyr-in-r)